# Arbitrage-free price $V_t^X$ for classical Black-Scholes model

Tags: brownian-motion, finance

I stumbled into this problem and as I was trying to solve it I got stuck. I found an answer for it but did not understand one step of it.

Consider the classical Black-Scholes model. We define a contingent claim $X$, which pays$$X= \max(S_T^\alpha -K,0)$$
at maturity $T>0$, for some constant $\alpha>0$

Determine the arbitrage-free price $V_t^X$ of $X$ at any time $t\in[0,T]$

I didn't have any problem understanding the first part as it is just applying the solution for the Geometric Brownian SDE

$V_t^X=e^{rt}E_Q[e^{-rT}\max(S_T^\alpha -K,0 )|F_t]$

$V_t^X =e^{-r(T-t)}E_Q[\max(S_t^\alpha e^{\alpha(r-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)(T-t)+\alpha\sigma(W_T^Q-W_t^Q)}-K,0)|F_t]$

$V_t^X =e^{-r(T-t)}E_Q[\max(S_t^\alpha e^{\alpha(r-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)(T-t)+\alpha\sigma(W_T^Q-W_t^Q)+\frac{1}{2}\alpha^2\sigma^2(T-t)-\frac{1}{2}\alpha^2\sigma^2(T-t)}-K,0)|F_t]$

The following step is what I didn't understand

$V_t^X =e^{-r(T-t)} S_t^\alpha e^{\alpha(r-\sigma^2)(T-t)+\frac{1}{2}\alpha^2\sigma^2(T-t)}E_Q[\max(e^{\alpha\sigma(W_T^Q-W_t^Q)-\frac{1}{2}\alpha^2\sigma^2(T-t)}-\frac{K}{S_t^\alpha e^{\alpha(r-\sigma^2)(T-t)+\frac{1}{2}\alpha^2\sigma^2(T-t)}},0)|F_t]$

Why is it that the term **$S_t^\alpha e^{\alpha(r-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)(T-t)}$** turns into

**$S_t^\alpha e^{\alpha(r-\sigma^2)(T-t)}$** when I take it out of the expectation ?

Comment: Could it just be a typo? Also, if the source is public, if you can cite where you are getting this from, it could be helpful.

Comment: I can't add the source, as this exercise is from an old exam.